# Redux: Modifying state in Reducers, is it acceptable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, immutability

In this example project, I have a login form and I have some actions that are waiting to be dispatched in cases of *verified login* or *failed login*.

These two actions are potentially triggered by an action that handles the submit event which talks to the backend. According to the response from the backend, it either fires *verified login* or *failed login*.

In order to react properly to these situations in the view layer, I have some booleans in the state. The reducer below modifies the state of these values according to trigger.

**Reducer**

```
import {FAILED_LOGIN, VERIFIED_LOGIN} from './../actions/LoginActions';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loginRejected: false,
    loginApproved: false,
    username: null,
    id: null,
    token: null
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FAILED_LOGIN:
        return {
            ...state,
            loginRejected: true
        };
    case VERIFIED_LOGIN:
        return {
            ...state,
            loginRejected: false,
            loginApproved: true,
            username: action.payload.data.email,
            id: action.payload.data._id,
            token: action.payload.headers['x-auth']
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Is it considered bad practice to mutate state like this in a reducer? I know I could return the values that I'm editing in the actions themselves and just assign the returned values in the reducer like I'm doing with user data, would you consider that a better practice over the current form?

Comment: Where is the mutation of state?

Comment: You are not mutating the state at all.   In fact, this is a good example of how actions and state should be handled.  The actions only contain the relevant data, and the reducers only modify the bits that need to change, leaving the state untouched.

Comment: I was considering maybe it was a better practice to handle this in the actions themselves rather than the reducer. But it seems to be that there's no difference between those two options.

Comment: @cinnaroll45 I do see a difference in that if you did it in your action, you would be dispatching a whole lot of additional info than the action pertains to.  Of the two options, what you have IS the better practise.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper Exactly, the action itself gets bloated and complicated when I do that. Glad to know that it's good practice, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @cinnaroll45 You seem to misunderstand what actions and reducers are for. Actions represent a command: "do this, and here is the data to be able to do it", while reducers actually perform this command merging the result into your state. That said your code looks fine, this is based on your first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not at all mutating the state. The way you are doing this totally fine and acceptable. By writing this

```
return {
            ...state,
            loginRejected: true
        };
```

you are actually creating a new object with the state and returning the new object without mutating the state. In fact the way you are doing is a kind of best practices.

Comment: I was considering maybe it was a better practice to handle this in the actions themselves rather than the reducer. But it seems to be that there's no difference between those two options.

Comment: Yes you can do that in action but then the half purpose of reducer is gone and also you will be writing a lot of code in the action which is not right.

Comment: It is reducer's job to alter the current state and then returning a new state according to the dispatched actions without mutating the current state which you are doing perfectly here.