# Redux and react. increase and decrease the quantity in a shopping cart. It really changed the quantity, but not re-render component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

this is code of reducer: an const array was used, state.Carts is the array hold the items add to cart.

```
    const initProductCart={
        numberCart: 0,
        Carts: [],//item trong gio
        _pizza:[//pizza
            {
                id: 'p1',
                img: product1,
                alt:'Pizza',
                name: 'Supreme Pizza',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 19.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            },
            {
                id:'p2',
                img: product2,
                alt:'Pizza',
                name: 'Supreme Pizza',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 16.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            },
            {
                id: 'p3',
                img: product3,
                alt:'Pizza',
                name: 'Supreme Pizza',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 14.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            }
        ],//item se doi lay tu api
    
        _sweet:[
            {
                id:'s1',
                img: sweet2,
                alt:'Donuts',
                name: 'Doughlicous',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 19.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            },
            {
                id:'s2',
                img: sweet3,
                alt:'Ice Cream',
                name: 'Caramel',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 16.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            },
            {
                id:'s3',
                img: sweet1,
                alt:'Brownie',
                name: 'Brownie Bunch',
                desc: 'marinara saurce, basil, italian saugage, roma tomatoes, olives, pesto',
                price: 14.99,
                button:'Add to Card',
            }
        ]
    }
    
    const cartReducer=(state=initProductCart, action)=>{
        switch(action.type){
            case GET_ALL_PRODUCT:
                return{
                    ...state,
                }
            case GET_NUMBER_CART:
                return{
                    ...state,
                }
            case ADD_CART:
                if(state.numberCart==0){
                    let cart={
                        id:action.payload.id,
                        quantity: 1,
                        img:action.payload.img,
                        name:action.payload.name,
                        price:action.payload.price
                    }
                    state.Carts.push(cart)
                }
                else{
                    let check=false;
                    state.Carts.map((item,key)=>{
                        if(item.id==action.payload.id){
                            state.Carts[key].quantity++;
                            check=true;
                        }
                    });
                    if(!check){
                        let _cart={
                            id:action.payload.id,
                            quantity: 1,
                            img:action.payload.img,
                            name:action.payload.name,
                            price:action.payload.price
                        }
                        state.Carts.push(_cart)
                    }
                }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    numberCart:state.numberCart+1,
                }
            case INCREASE_QUANTITY:
                state.numberCart++;
                state.Carts[action.payload].quantity++;
                console.log('reducer:'+state.Carts[action.payload].quantity)
                return{
                    ...state
                }
            case DECREASE_QUANTITY:
                let quantity= state.Carts[action.payload].quantity;
                if(quantity>1){
                    state.numberCart--;
                    state.Carts[action.payload].quantity--;
                }
                return{
                    ...state
                }
            case DELETE_CART:
                let _quantity= state.Carts[action.payload].quantity;
                return{
                    ...state,
                    numberCart:state.numberCart - _quantity,
                    Carts: state.Carts.filter(item=>{
                        return item.id!=state.Carts[action.payload].id
                    })
                }
        }
    }
    
    export default cartReducer;
```

code of cart component:

```
    const Orderpage = ({carts,IncreaseQuantity,DecreaseQuantity,DeleteCart}) => {
        let ListCart=[];
        let TotalCart=0;
        Object.keys(carts).forEach(function(item){
            TotalCart+=carts[item].quantity * carts[item].price;
            ListCart.push(carts[item]);
        });
        function TotalPrice(price,tonggia){
            return Number(price * tonggia).toLocaleString('en-US');
        }
        {console.log(ListCart)}
        return (
            // {Cart}
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            ListCart.map((item, key) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
    
                                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                                        <td><img src={item.img} style={{ width: '100px', height: '80px' }} /></td>
                                        <td>${item.price}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span className="btn btn-primary" style={{ margin: '2px' }}onClick={()=>DecreaseQuantity(key)}>-</span>
                                            {console.log('key: '+key)}
                                            <span className="btn btn-info">{item.quantity}</span>
                                            {console.log('quantity: '+item.quantity)}
                                            <span className="btn btn-primary" style={{ margin: '2px' }}onClick={()=>IncreaseQuantity(key)}>+</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{ TotalPrice(item.price,item.quantity)} $</td>
                                        <td><i className="badge badge-danger" onClick={()=>DeleteCart(key)}>X</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })
    
                        }
                        <tr>
                        <td colSpan="5">Total Carts</td>
                        <td>{Number(TotalCart).toLocaleString('en-US')} $</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
      
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state =>{
          return{
              carts: state.Carts
          }
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch=>{
        return{
    
        }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,{IncreaseQuantity,DecreaseQuantity,DeleteCart})(Orderpage)
```

[this is how it's working on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vCkG.png)
I clicked on button '+',then the quantity was increased, but I had to refresh the web and it re-render, it didn't automatically re-render.
[after click button '+'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2hB6.png)

Comment: In cartReducer, we see a lot of code mutating the state directly which is not recommended in redux.  check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467004/redux-modifying-state-in-reducers-is-it-acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are not using redux toolkit, where you can mutate state in your action functions.
So in current implementation you cannot mutate state and your reducer for increase/decrease should look like below:

```
    case INCREASE_QUANTITY:
        return{
            ...state,
            numberCart: state.numberCart + 1,
            Carts: {
                ...state.Carts,
                [action.payload]: {
                     ...state.Carts[action.payload],
                     quantity: state.Carts[action.payload].quantity + 1,
                },
            },
        }
    case DECREASE_QUANTITY:
        let quantity= state.Carts[action.payload].quantity;
        if(quantity>1){
            return{
                ...state,
                numberCart: state.numberCart - 1,
                Carts: {
                    ...state.Carts,
                    [action.payload]: {
                         ...state.Carts[action.payload],
                         quantity: state.Carts[action.payload].quantity - 1,
                    },
                },
            }
        }
        return state; // if not changed return unmutated state
```

You can read more about Why you should not mutate state in your reducer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531909/redux-why-is-avoiding-mutations-such-a-fundamental-part-of-using-it#:%7E:text=If%20you%20create%20a%20new,will%20not%20update%20the%20components.)

Comment: ```state.numberCart++;
state.Carts[action.payload].quantity++;``` I th

Comment: You are right, I have removed it. So ++ mutates state, as it changes property value without creating new one

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved and understanded my issue :V